# Combining Typescript Koa-Router and Passport

Tags: node.js, typescript, passport.js, koa2, koa-router

I am newb in Typescript and trying to integrate `koa-router` and `koa-passport`. Installed all `@types\`

```
import Koa from "koa";
import Route from "koa-router";
import passport from "koa-passport";
import session from "koa-session";

const app = new Koa();
const router = new Route();
app.keys = [process.env.SECRET_KEY || "secret"];
app.use(session({}, app));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods());
```

And when I try to use `passport` methods with `router`.

```
router.post("Logout", "/logout", ctx => {
  if (ctx.isAuthenticated()) {
    ctx.logout();
  }
});
```

have error on context(ctx) methods

```
Property 'isAuthenticated' does not exist on type 'ParameterizedContext<any, IRouterParamContext<any, {}>>'.
Property 'logout' does not exist on type 'ParameterizedContext<any, IRouterParamContext<any, {}>>'.
```

I tried different approaches, but unsuccessful. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you have any luck solving this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/36161#issuecomment-571295417

Answer (score 0):

I found one way is to define all routes with separate function and type definition of passport as `typeof KoaPassport`. And for route `as Koa.Middleware` had that issue too

```
// src/index.ts
import routes from "./routes";
...
routes(router, model, passport);
```

```
// src/routes/index.ts
function routes(router: Route, model: Model, passport: typeof KoaPassport) {
  router
        .post("Login", "/login", (async (ctx, next) => {
            await passport.authenticate("local", async (err, user) => {
                  ....
            })(ctx, next);
        }) as Koa.Middleware)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I found was to use

```js
const router = new Route<{}, koa.Context>();
```

The koa-router types adds the passport methods to `koa.Context` in https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/koa-passport/index.d.ts#L23. The 2nd type parameter for `Router` lets us add extra properties to the middleware context. By passing in `koa.Context`, we get access to the functions added by koa-router.